# How to convert CR to CRLF line endings on a file?

Tags: text-processing, conversion, newlines

An ASCII text file, with `CR` line terminators, (Mac style) needs to be converted to have `CRLF` line terminators (DOS/Windows style).

Search for `CR` not followed by `LF`, and replace that `CR` with a `CRLF`. So a duplicate command won't ruin the file (with `CRCRLF`).

I have tried `unix2dos`, but that fails in doing the conversion.

How can this file be converted on a base Arch Linux console without Python / vim?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you install the `dos2unix` utility (a utility that will convert files from DOS to Unix text format) you will also get the `mac2unix` and `unix2dos` utilities that performs the conversion from Mac text file to Unix text file format and from Unix to DOS, respectively. You may then combine `mac2unix` with `unix2dos` to convert from Mac to DOS text format, using Unix text as an intermediate format:

```bash
mac2unix myfile
unix2dos myfile
```

It is safe to run this several times on the same file or set of files.

Note that BusyBox (as found on e.g. Alpine Linux) has a built-in `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` command but no `mac2unix` command.  On BusyBox systems, you therefore also need to install the `dos2unix` package to get access to `mac2unix`.

Comment: `mac2unix myfile && unix2dos myfile` is found to be working. The file is now "ASCII text, with CRLF line terminators". And even 2 bytes smaller then the answer that uses `perl`.

Answer (score 2):

Mac2dos file conversion is possible with perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\r\n/g' input-file.txt > output-file.crlf
```

Or inline:

```
$ perl -pi -e 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\r\n/g' file-to-convert
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14155400/529778 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/6374360/529778

Comment: Why down vote this answer? It is tested and found to be working....

Comment: You are reinventing the wheel... That's why I downvoted. There are tools mentioned above which are likely even more reliable / faster / simply good enough.

Comment: @VlastimilBurián None of dos2unix, mac2unix, unix2dos, or unix2mac are installed on my servers and they are not installed as  default packages in OEL 8 (and I assume Rocky, Alma, and REL). Perl however is installed so you can put this one-liner in a shell alias and not have to install extra packages. Reinventing the wheel is not a bad thing when the wheel is not available.

Comment: That would convert a standalone `\n` to `\r\n` when it occurs anywhere in the input, even if it's not intended to represent a newline, and I'm guessing it'd also have to read the whole input file so YMMV depending on how large that is.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked "How can this file be converted on a base Arch Linux console without ..." - using any awk in any shell on every Unix box without having to install anything and without reading the whole input file into memory, this will convert all CRs to CRLFs:

```
awk -v RS='\r' -v ORS='\r\n' '1'
```

e.g.:

```
$ printf 'foo\rbar\r' | cat -ve
foo^Mbar^M$
```

```
$ printf 'foo\rbar\r' | awk -v RS='\r' -v ORS='\r\n' '1' | cat -ve
foo^M$
bar^M$
```

You also said "So a duplicate command won't ruin the file (with CRCRLF)" but I don't think there is a way to handle the command being called again robustly because it's impossible to tell by reading input whether any `\r\n`s in it were placed there by a previous run of the tool or if there just happen to be `\n`s after the `\r`s in the original input so - don't do that!